# How to reveal current file in Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When I have a file opened, I'd like to have a shortcut to navigate to this file inside the `EXPLORER`, so that I can see where it is located.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

In the command palette (<kbd>F1</kbd>), there is a `Files: Reveal Active File in Side Bar` command. You can assign a shortcut to it via the keyboard shortcuts editor:

[image]

Alternatively, you could try the [Reveal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=smulyono.reveal) extension which adds this button to editors:

[image]

It might make sense to disable auto-reveal when using this shortcut as a "manual reveal":

```json
// Set this in your settings.json file
"explorer.autoReveal": false
```

Comment: `Shift+Command+P`, enter `Files: Reveal Active File in Side Bar`

Comment: In fresh download of current VSC (version 1.49.3) on Win 10, command palette does not have `Files: Reveal Active File in Side Bar`. Instead, do [rt-click on file tab above source pane / reveal in side bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44844331/199364)

Comment: I bound the command `workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer` to Ctrl + K B, as R and S were already taken :)

Comment: Is the same thing possible, but with **revealing the file in the *Folders* panel instead**, please? There are several panels in the *Explorer* sidebar (*Open editors*, *Folders*, *Outline*, *Timeline*, *Documentation*, etc.) and the suggested function reveals it in the *Open editors* panel, which has very limited possibilities of what you can do with files there (compare context menus of a file in both panels). In the *Folders* panel, you can rename, delete and copy&paste files, open their timeline, history, etc.

Comment: I don't find this functionality very useful.  In addition to the points raised by @DavidFerenczyRogožan, files in the same folder typically share a common focus/purpose; for this reason, when I'm viewing/editing a file, I often want to browse through the files near it in the folder tree.  A command to reveal the active file in the folder tree would make this easy to do.

Sometimes, the "reveal active file in sidebar" cmd does reveal it in the folder tree, though the behavior is inconsistent.

Answer (score 32):

To show the active file in the Windows-Explorer or sidebar:

- right-click on the file tab and choose 'reveal in explorer'/'reveal in side bar'

[image]

The keyboard shortcut for reveal in windows explorer is is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>

To show the file in the sidebar you can assign a custom code in the keybindings window:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your tip but i'm looking for a keybinding shortcut. Also,  'reveal in explorer' actually opens it up in the windows explorer. I'm talking about the VS Code explorer here :)

Answer (score 21):

Just press Cmd + Shift + E and the explorer will show the file you are viewing.

Comment: For me it doesn't work on files the appear in .gitignore since I didn't enable it in the settings under `Features -> Explorer -> Exclude Git Ignore`

Answer (score 8):

Wanted to add that the first answer still works, but that the text was slightly changed to "Reveal in Explorer View" from "Reveal file in sidebar"

[image]

and

right clicking on the tab

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Tested in Visual Studio Code 1.78.0 on Linux Ubuntu 20.04.*

No extensions are needed.

Several additional easy ways:

1. [already mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44844331/4561887), where I first learned it]

   Right-click the file tab of interest at the top of the window --> "Reveal in Explorer View", as shown here:
   [image]
2. The following ways *only* work if you have either *not* set a value for `"explorer.autoReveal"` (since its default value is `true`), *or* if you have explicitly set it to `true` inside your `settings.json` file, like this:

   ```json
   // Controls whether the Explorer should automatically reveal and select
   // files when opening them.
   //  - true: Files will be revealed and selected.
   //  - false: Files will not be revealed and selected.
   //  - focusNoScroll: Files will not be scrolled into view, but will still be
   //    focused.
   // GS note: default is `true`
   "explorer.autoReveal": true,
   ```

   1. [not explained in any other answer yet]

      Click the "Refresh Explorer" button at the top of the File Explorer view:

      [image]
   2. [not explained in any other answer yet]

      Click *any other file tab* at the top of the Window (assuming you have multiple files open), then click back to your file of interest.
   3. [not explained in any other answer yet]

      Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to navigate one file tab to the right (assuming you have multiple files open), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> to navigate back to your original file one tab back to the left.

### See also the two main answers:

1. [By @Gama11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44845266/4561887) - where I learned about the reveal command, the Reveal extension, and the `"explorer.autoReveal"` settings.json setting.
2. [By @jps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44844331/4561887) - where I learned about the Right Click --> "Reveal in Explorer View" menu option.